# Powershell DataTable,Select Filter does not accept single quote character

Tags: powershell, select, filter, datatable, quote

I'm writing a simple Name search against a datatable using Powershell.  The code as following:

```
    $filter = "Name = '$aContact'"
    $arow = $dt_resources.Select($filter)
```

This works all fine except if $aContact contains a single quote (') character, like "O'Connor".

Any ideal how can I workaround this issue?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Double any `'` to escape it: `$filter = "Name = '$($aContact.Replace("'", "''"))'"`

Comment: Thank you so much Mathias, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626222/powershell-datatable-select-filter-does-not-accept-single-quote-character#comment124851525_70626222) already commented on the solution to the question but to put it as an answer, you can escape the `'` by doubling them. I added a simple function that will also serve as workaround for possible `$null` input since both methods (`.Contains` and `.Replace`) would throw an exception in that case.

```
$dtt = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
'Name', 'Value' | ForEach-Object{
    $dtt.Columns.Add([System.Data.DataColumn]::new($_))
}
$row = $dtt.NewRow()
$row.Name = "O'Connor"
$row.Value = [random]::new().Next()
$dtt.Rows.Add($row)
$row = $dtt.NewRow()
$row.Name = "Doe"
$row.Value = [random]::new().Next()
$dtt.Rows.Add($row)

function CheckQuery {
param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$Value
)
    if($Value.Contains("'")) { return $Value.Replace("'","''") }
    return $Value
}

"O'Connor", "Doe", $null | ForEach-Object {
    $filter = "Name = '{0}'" -f ($_ | CheckQuery)
    $dtt.Select($filter)
}
```